# replace byte in 32 bit number

Tags: c

I have a function called `replaceByte(x,n,c)` that is to replace byte `n` in `x` with `c` with the following restrictions:

- Bytes numbered from 0 (LSB) to 3 (MSB)
- Examples: `replaceByte(0x12345678,1,0xab) = 0x1234ab78`
- You can assume 0 <= n <= 3 and 0 <= c <= 255
- Legal ops: `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`
- Max ops: 10

  ```
  int replaceByte(int x, int n, int c) {
          int shift = (c << (8 * n));
          int mask = 0xff << shift;
          return (mask & x) | shift;
      }
  ```

but when I test it I get this error:

ERROR: Test replaceByte(-2147483648[0x80000000],0[0x0],0[0x0]) failed...
...Gives 0[0x0]. Should be -2147483648[0x80000000]

after realizing that * is not a legal operator I have finally figured it out...and if you are curious, this is what I did:

```
int replaceByte(int x, int n, int c) {
  int mask = 0xff << (n << 3);
  int shift = (c << (n << 3));
  return (~mask & x) | shift;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change

```
return (mask & x) | shift;
```

to

```
return (~mask & x) | shift;
```

The `mask` should contain all ones except for the region to be masked and not vice versa.

I am using this simple code and it works fine in GCC.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int replaceByte(int x, int n, int c) 
{
    int shift = (c << (n << 3));
    int mask = 0xff << shift; // mask = 0xff << (n << 3)
    return (~mask & x) | shift;
}

int main ()
{
    printf("%X",replaceByte(0x80000000,0,0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how -> "int mask = 0xff << shift;" works for you. Seems incorrect to me. Like OP updated should probably be "int mask = 0xff << (n << 3);"

Answer (score 7):

Since this looks like homework I'm not going to post code, but list the steps you need to perform:

1. Cast `c` into a 32-bit number so you don't lose any bits while shifting
2. Next, shift `c` by the appropriate number of bits to the left (if `n==0` no shifting, if `n==1` shift by 8 etc.)
3. Create a 32-bit bitmask that will zero the lowest 8 bits of `x`, then shift this mask by the same amount as the last step
4. Perform bitwise AND of the shifted bitmask and `x` to zero out the appropriate bits of `x`
5. Perform bitwise OR (or addition) of the shifted `c` value and `x` to replace the masked bits of the latter

Comment: ok I understand all of that except for the part where you say "Create a 32-bit bitmask that will zero the lowest 8 bits of x..."

Comment: @shaynie Before you go about replacing the bits of `x` you need to zero the 8 bits that are going to be replaced. That's where that bitmask comes in.

Comment: ok that makes sense, I put some code up above that I have submitted and the error that I am recieving

Comment: @shaynie The mask you're using is doing the exact opposite of what you want. You're zeroing *everything but* the 8 bits you want to replace. You can fix it by bit inverting your existing mask manually, or apply the [bitwise NOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46zxf1c0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operator to your existing mask. The second option is more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Proper solution is for c = 0 as well:

```
     int replaceByte(int x, int n, int c)
     {
        int shift = 8 * n;
        int value = c << shift;
        int mask = 0xff << shift;

        return (~mask & x) | value;
     }
```